# Is the Stack Exchange APP for Android still available?

Tags: support, notifications

I have used the Stack Exchange APP for Android before and found it useful (a bit limited). I don't see it in the Play Store for Android. Also, I don't anymore see a reference to the APP here on Stack Exchange.

I can't get the original from my old phone (drowned phone). Is the App still available, and if so where can it be found?

Tag : "notifications" is the best tag I could find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not available. See [Why did the Stack Exchange Android app disappear from the Play Store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353133/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. The company has stopped supporting the mobile apps altogether: [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/295232)

Comment: Aha !  I didn't think to check on the Main "Meta Stack Exchange".